# Overriding styles based on parent with css modules

Tags: css, css-modules

So I am working in react and have a `SvgIcon` component that has it own default styles and a `Button` component that has its own default styles using css modules. What I am looking to do is I need to have the `SvgIcon` component have slightly different style when it is inside of a `Button` component. With standard SASS I would just do this in the button styling:

```
.button {
  .svg-icon {
    fill: $grey3;
  }
}
```

Since the class names with css modules are random hashes of sorts, I can't think of a good way to do this.

I could pass an extra class name to the `SvgIcon` component that comes from the button styles but I would have to remember doing that each time I want to use a `SvgIcon` component inside a `Button` component (or I could create a `ButtonSvgIcon` component but that pattern could lead to a ton of these really dumb components for just styling which feels wrong in my gut). This also has the problem that if the `SvgIcon` component is included after the `Button` component, it will override the css the button applies since I have a lot less control in the order my css is generated in this fashion compare to stuff like sass (though I think the `ButtonSvgIcon` component would address this issue).

I could also have the `SvgIcon` override style in the `SvgIcon` component's styles code however that seems to be backwards as far of component knowledge (it make a lot more sense for the component that is using another component, in this case the `Button` using the `SvgIcon`, to override the style instead of the component that might be used in any number of other components needing to override all those styles).

Is there a standard way to address override the style of one component when it is in the context of another component with css modules?

Comment: Did u find a solution for this problem?